# List of known circuits and their expected output

Tags: resource-request, simulation, circuit-construction

I've written an API which takes in a circuit scaffold, according to some specifications, and outputs the results of simulating the circuit.  The circuit constraints are that the measurements are performed optionally at the end.  I want to test the API against known quantum circuit results.

I was wondering if there was a online resource which tabulates a list of known circuits and their results/outputs?  An online quantum simulator would also work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe [Quirk](https://algassert.com/quirk) would suit your needs? It's an in-browser, graphical quantum-circuit simulator. You can build your circuit with drag-and-drop and it will show the probabilities of measurements. However, there is a limit to the number of qubits you can simulate. I think it is 16 or so.

Comment: Hi, nikojpapa. Welcome to Quantum Computing SE! [We discourage link-only answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/416888). Please consider briefly summarizing the functionality of the software you linked. Thanks!

Comment: Edited to summarize the link.